# Seekbar using custom 9-patch images for progress and background

Tags: android, seekbar, nine-patch

I'm trying to implement SeekBar with custom progress and backround.

Seekbar

```
<SeekBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:thumbOffset="0dp"
            android:maxHeight="6dp"
            android:tag="seekbar"
            android:thumb="@drawable/circle_seekbar_player_fragment"                   android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress_player_fragment"/>
```

styled_progress_player_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_backgroun">
        </item>

    <!--<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corners_seekbar_transparent"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>-->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progres"
            android:scaleWidth="100%"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Background seekbar_backgroun.9.png
[image]
Progress image seekbar_progres.9.png
[image]

In 9patch window it is scaled as i want:
[image]

But in my app it's acting strange or maybe i'm not doing smthng right
[image]

Can you help me so my seekbar look fine

**EDIT**
Problem solved. The problem was that when i use ninepatch it uses resolurion in px not in dp, that's why it was scaling down
I fixed it by placing this ninepatch images to xxhdpi folder

Comment: What do you mean by  "it's acting strange"? What's wrong in your result?

Comment: look attentively on the left and right edges. they are scaling differently then i exptected

Comment: Problem is that you did not provide this 9-patch for different dpi(s) ... default is mdpi ... and on xhdpi device it can looks "ugly" :)

Comment: sorry but these images are for my xxhdpi device they have 24px height and in layout it's 6dp, 6*4=24